# Getting error in reactjs TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux

I am making a job portal project using react js and for state management I am using Redux . i was trying to make "search" component to get  the listed jobs from the backend but getting an error that says the filter method is undefined

Here is my "searchJobs" action

```
export const searchJobs = (searchkey) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    var filteredJobs;
    const { response } = await axios.get(
      "https://ajob-backend.herokuapp.com/api/getalljobs"
    );
    filteredJobs = response;
    if (searchkey) {
      filteredJobs = response.filter((job) => {
        return job.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchkey.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
    dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_JOBS, payload: filteredJobs });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

and here is my search component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { searchJobs } from "../redux/actions/jobActions";


function Search() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [searchkey,setSearchkey]=useState("")
  }
  const searchFinish=()=>{
    dispatch(searchJobs(searchkey))
  }
  return (
       
          <>

                <div className="product-search-container">
               <div className="input-group">
                <div className="form-outline">
                  <input type="search" id="form1" className="form-control"
                   value={searchkey}  
                  onChange={(e)=>{
                    setSearchkey(e.target.value)
                  }}
                   />
                  <label className="form-label" for="form1">
                    Search
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>{
                dispatch(searchJobs(searchkey))
                }}>
                  <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>

           </>       
  );
}

export default Search;
```

let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
filteredJobs = await response.data;
```

What might have happened is that axios returns a promise and if you set
`filteredJobs = response.data`, your code is now iterating through an `undefined` object because your fetching code runs asynchronously.

I've only had experience with `.fetch` but if axios returns a promise then you would have to `await` the accessed properties of the promise.

If I'm wrong, I'm wrong, lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make sure it first, if the response is an array, because filter method can be called if the object is an array, for the detail maybe you can check via this link: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116519/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-filter-of-undefined-react), I Hope this will help you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i changed the my "searchjob" action.

```
export const searchJobs = (searchkey) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    var filteredJobs;
    const  response  = await axios.get(
      "https://ajob-backend.herokuapp.com/api/getalljobs"
    );
    filteredJobs = response.data;
    if (searchkey) {
      filteredJobs = response.data.filter((job) => {
        return job.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchkey.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
    dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_JOBS, payload: filteredJobs });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```